# React Native Interactable for Android not working

Tags: javascript, react-native

I'm trying to do a [workaround for this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44664953/3935156) where if the [interactable.view](https://github.com/wix/react-native-interactable) snaps to the top of the screen then the button is not rendered and if it snaps to the bottom of the screen then the button is rendered, by utilising `onSnap` property of the `Interactable.View`:

code:

```
    <Interactable.View
      style={{
        height: Screen.height,
        width: '100%',
        zIndex: 19,
        backgroundColor: '#222222',
        position: 'absolute',
        padding: 20
      }}
      onSnap={(e) => {
        if(e.nativeEvent.index === 2) {
          this.setState({showButton: false})
        } else {
          this.setState({showButton: true})
        }
      }}
      boundaries={{ top: 0, bounce: 0.5 }}
      verticalOnly={true}
      snapPoints={[
        { y: (Platform.OS === 'ios') ? Screen.height - 55 : Screen.height - 85, damping: 0.7 },
        { y: (Platform.OS === 'ios') ? Screen.height - 190 : Screen.height - 230, damping: 0.7 },
        { y: 0, damping: 0.7 }
      ]}
      initialPosition={{ x: 0, y: (Platform.OS === 'ios') ? Screen.height - 55 : Screen.height - 85 }}


      ref={view => this.interactableView2 = view}>

    </Interactable.View>

    {this.state.showButton &&
      <Button
        small
        icon
        ref={view => this.button1 = view}
        style={mapStyle.toggleMenuButton}
        onPress={() => {
          this.interactableView.snapTo({ index: 0 })
          this.props.onToggleMenuClick()
          this.props.setSelectedShop({ id: -1 })
          this.props.updateSearchResults({ products: [] })
        }}>
        <Icon name="sliders" size={20} color="#FFFFFF" />
      </Button>
    }
```

It works on iOS and on android it somehow stops the `Interactable.View` from even moving to the top, and the button just loses it's icon, and becomes unclickable. No errors are shown in the console.

Any ideas why Android is being so buggy?

**EDIT: Here is the style of the button that should disappear:**

```
export default {
  toggleMenuButton: {
    top: 30,
    left: 10,
    width: 50,
    position: 'absolute',
    zIndex: 5,
    height: 50,
    borderRadius: 25,
    backgroundColor: '#FF3B3F',
    shadowColor: '#000000',
    shadowOffset: {
      width: 0,
      height: 1
    },
    shadowRadius: 1,
    shadowOpacity: 1.0
  }
}
```

**EDIT: full code:**

**Map.js**

```
import {
  StyleSheet,
  View,
  Text,
  FlatList,
  TouchableHighlight,
  Dimensions,
  Platform,
  //findNodeHandle,
  Image
} from 'react-native'
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import MapView from 'react-native-maps'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import {
  Button,
  Container
} from 'native-base'

import { updateRegion } from './map.action'
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/FontAwesome'
import { toggleMenu } from '../search-page/searchPage.action'
import mapStyle from './style'
import Interactable from 'react-native-interactable'
import { setSelectedShop } from '../search-results/searchResults.action'
import { updateHeight } from '../search-results/searchResultsPresenter.action'
import { getSelectedProduct } from './markers.selector'
import { updateSearchResults } from '../search-page/searchPage.action'
//import { BlurView } from 'react-native-blur'


const Screen = {
  width: Dimensions.get('window').width,
  height: Dimensions.get('window').height
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  region: state.get('map').get('region'),
  markers: state.get('searchResults').get('products'),
  selectedProduct: getSelectedProduct(state)
})

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
  onRegionChange: (region) => {
    dispatch(updateRegion(region))
  },
  updateSearchResults: (results) => {
    dispatch(updateSearchResults(results))
  },
  onToggleMenuClick: () => {
    dispatch(toggleMenu())
  },
  setSelectedShop: id => {
    dispatch(setSelectedShop(id))
  },
  updateHeight: height => {
    dispatch(updateHeight(height))
  }
})

class Map extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    //this.state = { viewRef: null }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    const { store } = this.context
    this.unsubscribe = store.subscribe(() => { })
    //this.setState({ viewRef: findNodeHandle(this.viewToBlur) })
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    this.unsubscribe()
  }

  interactableView;
  interactableView2;

  render() {
    return (
      <Container>
        <MapView
          style={styles.map}
          region={this.props.region}
          onRegionChangeComplete={this.props.onRegionChange}>
          {
            this.props.markers.map(marker => {
              return (
                <MapView.Marker
                  coordinate={marker.shop.coordinate}
                  title={marker.shop.name}
                  identifier={marker.shop.id.toString()}
                  onPress={e => {
                    console.log(e.nativeEvent)
                    this.interactableView.snapTo({ index: 1 })
                    this.props.setSelectedShop(marker.shop)
                    console.log(this.props.selectedProduct)
                  }}
                />
              )
            })
          }
        </MapView>

//********************************************************************//
                 the button
//********************************************************************//

        <Button
          small
          icon
          style={mapStyle.toggleMenuButton}
          onPress={() => {
            this.interactableView.snapTo({ index: 0 })
            this.props.onToggleMenuClick()
            this.props.setSelectedShop({ id: -1 })
            this.props.updateSearchResults({ products: [] })
          }}>
          <Icon name="sliders" size={20} color="#FFFFFF" />
        </Button>

//********************************************************************//
                 the interactable.view
//********************************************************************//

        <Interactable.View
          style={{
            height: Screen.height,
            width: '100%',
            zIndex: 19,
            backgroundColor: '#222222',
            position: 'absolute',
            borderRadius: 10,
            padding: 20
          }}
          boundaries={{ top: 0, bounce: 0.5 }}
          verticalOnly={true}
          snapPoints={[
            { y: (Platform.OS === 'ios') ? Screen.height - 55 : Screen.height - 85, damping: 0.7 },
            { y: (Platform.OS === 'ios') ? Screen.height - 190 : Screen.height - 230, damping: 0.7 },
            { y: 0, damping: 0.7 }
          ]}
          initialPosition={{ x: 0, y: (Platform.OS === 'ios') ? Screen.height - 55 : Screen.height - 85 }}


          ref={view => this.interactableView2 = view}>

          </Interactable.View>


        <Interactable.View
          style={{
            height: Screen.height,
            width: '100%',
            zIndex: 20,
            backgroundColor: '#222222',
            borderRadius: 10,
            padding: 20
          }}
          boundaries={{ top: 0, bounce: 0.5 }}
          verticalOnly={true}
          snapPoints={[{ y: (Platform.OS === 'ios') ? Screen.height - 55 : Screen.height - 85, damping: 0.7 },
          { y: (Platform.OS === 'ios') ? Screen.height - 190 : Screen.height - 230, damping: 0.7 }]}
          initialPosition={{ x: 0, y: (Platform.OS === 'ios') ? Screen.height - 55 : Screen.height - 85 }}
          ref={view => this.interactableView = view}>
          <View
            style={{ width: '100%', height: 200 }}>
            <Text
              style={{
                color: 'white',
                marginTop: (Platform.OS === 'ios') ? 0 : 2,
                marginBottom: (Platform.OS === 'ios') ? 20 : 25,
                textAlign: 'center',
                width: '100%'
              }}>
              {this.props.selectedProduct ? this.props.selectedProduct.shop.name : ''}
            </Text>
            {this.props.selectedProduct ? (
              <FlatList
                horizontal={true}
                style={{
                  height: 200
                }}
                data={this.props.selectedProduct ? this.props.selectedProduct.products : [{ name: '' }]}
                renderItem={({ item }) => {
                  return (
                    <TouchableHighlight onPress={() => this.interactableView2.snapTo({ index: 2 })}>
                      <View

                        //ref={x => this.viewToBlur = x}
                        style={{ width: 100, marginRight: 20 }}>
                        {/*<View style={{
                          borderWidth: 1,
                          borderColor: 'black',
                          margin: 0,
                          backgroundColor: 'red'
                        }} />*/}
                        {item.image ? (
                        <Image
                          style={{
                            width: 100,
                            height: 100,
                            zIndex: 45
                          }}
                          source={{ uri: item.image }}
                        />) : (
                          <Image
                          style={{
                            width: 100,
                            height: 100,
                            zIndex: 45
                          }}
                          source={ require('../add-page/noimage.png') }
                        />
                        )}

                        <Text style={{
                          color: 'white',
                          width: '100%',
                          textAlign: 'center'
                        }}>{item.name}</Text>
                      </View>

                    </TouchableHighlight>
                  )
                }} />) : <View />}
          </View>
          {/*<BlurView
            style={{
              position: 'absolute',
              top: 0,
              bottom: 0,
              left: 0,
              right: 0,
              borderWidth: 1,
              borderColor: 'black',
              zIndex: 60
            }}
            blurType="dark"
            viewRef={this.state.viewRef}
            blurAmount={20}
            blurRadius={20} />*/}
        </Interactable.View>
      </Container >
    )
  }
}



Map.contextTypes = {
  store: React.PropTypes.object
}

Map.propTypes = {
  region: React.PropTypes.shape({
    latitude: React.PropTypes.number,
    longitude: React.PropTypes.number,
    latitudeDelta: React.PropTypes.number,
    longitudeDelta: React.PropTypes.number
  }).isRequired,
  updateHeight: React.PropTypes.func,
  setSelectedShop: React.PropTypes.func,
  selectedProduct: React.PropTypes.object,
  onRegionChange: React.PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  onToggleMenuClick: React.PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  markers: React.PropTypes.array,
  updateSearchResults: React.PropTypes.func
}

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(Map)

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  map: {
    ...StyleSheet.absoluteFillObject,
    zIndex: 3
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

We can't see your style here but it looks like the same issue you had in the linked question.

`elevation` overrides `zIndex`, so it could make your button be on top of the view but since `React Native` calculates your touches according to `zIndex` and completely ignoring `elevation` - your button is on top, but touches are actually going to the view with the higher `zIndex` which is drawn below it. Had the same thing happen to me, took me a day to realize what the issue was.

Comment: Thanks, although this doesn't appear to be the solution for me unfortunately. I remove the elevation entirely and the issue remains. It also wouldn't explain why my workaround creates a new and strange bug on Android.

Comment: What strange bug does it create? I think I described the same thing you did, I had the same issue. Also, please add the style of `toggleMenuButton` so we can give you better help.

Comment: I just updated the question with the styling now. The bug: on Android it somehow stops the `Interactable.View` from even moving to the top of the screen, and the button stays visible and just loses it's icon, and becomes untappable. So basically on iOS the button disappears when it should, and on Android it never disappears. Thanks.

Comment: Still a lot of details missing to fully understand the source of the issue.
I don't see the parent of `Interactable.View` so I can't say why it doesn't reach the top, and the code that hides the button is very unclear when looking at it like this.
If you could reproduce with an Expo link, that would help.

Comment: I have too many third party libraries to do an expo sorry but i have posted the full code now.